# Getting left and right floats to overlap instead of stack

Tags: html, css, layout, css-float

This is easier to show than explain: http://jsfiddle.net/gN4VZ/

[image]

Is it possible to have my right-floated content (blue) overlap my left-floated content (red) instead of stack below it when the two combine to exceed the container width?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could use [absolute positioning](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#absolute-positioning).

*Instead of*

```
float: right
```

*use:*

```
position: absolute;
right: 0;
```

*and instead of*

```
float: left
```

*use:*

```
position: absolute;
left: 0;
```

Be sure to set `position: relative;` on your parent `div`s so that the absolute positioning is relative to their respective containers instead of the page.

Comment: It might be better to only position one of these absolutely. That way you can still get a stacking effect if any content goes below. (Assuming both divs are the saem height anyway)

Answer (score 2):

Use absolute positioning with the `.box` class set to `position:relative`.

http://jsfiddle.net/gN4VZ/1/

Note that I had to set a height on each `.box` so that it wouldnt overlap top/bottom.

your new CSS would be

```
.bar {
    border:solid 1px black;
    color:white;
    position:relative;
    height:40px;
}
.clear {
    clear:both;
}
.left-bar {
    background:red;
    height:40px;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
}
.right-bar {
    background:blue;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    height:40px;
}​
```

---

as suggested by My Head Hurts, you could just position the right one, which eliminates the need for the height on the outer div.

http://jsfiddle.net/gN4VZ/2/

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer- (Gave to Wanovak since beat you by a min)

Comment: sure :)  He did have it faster.